# Converting XML like document to XML

Tags: .net, xml

I have a document that is very close in format to XML that I get from an outside source (I cannot have it fixed at the source).  But this software was at one point an industry standard so it is in the hands of a whole lot of our users, and replacing these system could cost our users big bucks.  They won't do it.  Sometimes this document comes in as perfectly formatted XML, but in certain scenarios the document has invalid text in the `InnerText` of some of the elements. One such example is `<=>`.  I'm finding these in places that would have been texts fields that the were input by the user, and the source application did not clean at the time of generation of the would be XML document.

I have a .net application that is reading this document with an `XmlReader` object. In most cases it succeeds, because in most cases the document is a valid XML document.  But if I get a document which isn't an XML document it throws an exception for obvious reasons.

Does anybody know of a way to convert this document to XML before the load?  Or else is there a way to make the `XmlReader` handle errors more gracefully?  The data that prevents this document from being a valid XML document is not actually important to me and could just be thrown away.  Anything that is important to me is formatted as valid XML.

Comment: You could pre-process the document and look for specific invalid sequences and clean them up before feeding the document to the XMLReader.

Comment: The problem is that there is no specific pattern. This is user generated data that the source system just injected into their XML without cleaning it.

Comment: I updated the question to reflect the fact that this document isn't technically an XML document.  Though I feel that that was sort of a nitpicky down vote.

Comment: @mike after staring at the  file in a "format other than XML" I did find a pattern, wasn't easy to spot but I found one that I think will suffice. Well at least until the next error arises. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other system is not giving you XML. Don't think of it as invalid XML, or almost XML, or XML that has errors in it. Think of it as YXQ. If someone is sending you data in format YXQ, you need first to get hold of (or write) a specification of ehat YXQ is, then you need to write a parser for it, perhaps a parser that translates it into XML. Perhaps YXQ is similar enough to the language that some existing parser like TagSoup or validator.nu will process; you could try it and see, assuming you have a large enough sample of YXQ to make your tests meaningful.

Alternatively, there's a very good standard interchange format which many people use, called XML. It has the great advantage that parsers already exist, on every conceivable platform. People save themselves a great deal of money by using it. Why not suggest it to your data supplier? They might find that they acquire more customers.

Comment: I can't tell if this is a serious answer or not

Comment: I updated the question to clarify the fact that this is not technically XML that I'm receiving.  It would be nice for the down vote to go away.  I guess I should have thought about the way I worded the question, there was never any point in time that I thought the file was XML, I just thought that the smart people in the stack overflow community could deduce that fact on their own and maybe make some actual suggestions towards helping me solve this problem.  I'd prefer not to have myself or one of my teammates needs to manually fix this in the rare occasion in which it occurs.

Comment: @Saggio - I think it's serious.  I got a serious down vote that I don't believe that I deserved.

Comment: It is a serious answer, though I apologize for the sarcasm. I believe passionately in the importance of standards conformance. Many engineering failures occur when people cut corners by accepting sub-standard components and "bending them to fit". They think they are being pragmatic, but they are actually sowing the seeds of subsequent catastrophic system failures. It's unprofessional conduct.

Comment: @MichaelKay I Agree with you on that, but was it really necessary for you to come on here and belittle me as you did.  I have a low Stack Overflow rep, because I just go into actually interacting with the community, but I'm no noob.  Believe me this frustrates me a lot more than it frustrates you, but it's way out of my hands.  I have no choice but to deal with this mess. This piece of software that is the source for this nightmare is huge.  I guarantee you've indirectly used this software many times in your life.  This system is intertwined in all of our lives.  I would have loved for them...

Comment: to obey the standard but they didn't.  It would cost our customers a lot of money to change to a new system, and from their point of view this one is not broken.  I understood from the get go that this was not XML by definition, but the Stack Overflow community is smart, and I didn't expect me calling this document XML to be taken so literally.  I will try to be more specific of my understanding of the problem in the future to try to avoid answers like this.

Comment: I know, sorry I'm being harsh, I know that it's easier to take a moralistic stance when you haven't got managers and customers breathing down your neck to ship something yesterday. But in the end, when we sacrifice engineering principles and bow to such pressures, we end up paying the price: and in the long term, the price is much higher than doing it right the first time.

Comment: Again, I do agree with you on that.  The thing is that the source company has long since moved on from this product, they have a newer much better piece of software which we also support, but many companies invested a lot of money into this thing, and they will not upgrade until they need to.  A malformed document is not enough to convince non-technical money people to spend, hundreds of thousands up to millions (depending on the size of the system) to upgrade. Anyway I did solve my problem there was a pattern, I convert it to valid XML by wrapping the user data in a `CDATA` section...

Comment: and everything seems to be working well.  As you are obviously quite knowledgeable in this domain, I would like to ask you one final question.  I have not used the `CDATA` section in the past.  Will this always work?  Is there anything that I need to watch out for with this solution? Thanks for your time. And apology accepted.

Comment: Wrapping stuff in CDATA will get it past the XML parser, but you still have the problem downstream of dealing with what's in the CDATA sections. Also watch out for the fact that CDATA sections can't be nested: the first ']]>' terminates all levels of nesting.

Comment: Sounds good.  I don't think any of that will cause a problem.  The only thing thing I need to look out for in the case is the sub-string `"]]>"` as all of the text in these blocks is to be taken literally, they were never meant for the user to inject there own XML.  I appreciate your help, and while I didn't like the tone of the answer, I did learn from the discussion that it invoked, and it is correct so I'll give it you.  Thanks again.